# Retrieve the input written in the text area from the frontend to backend

Tags: html, r, reactjs

I am facing one issue with the content written in HTML textarea. The input in the textarea (front-end -React) will come to the backend (R). But here the actual problem.

Input in the text-area from front-end:

```
Eg: A > 100
    AND
    B > 140
```

Expected input in the back-end from front-end:

```
Eg: A > 100\nAND\nB > 140
```

I am getting the input from the front-end, but without first '\n'.

```
Eg: A>100AND\nB > 140
```

The first \n is missing. I have checked for a while but didn't found anything related to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to research about character escaping
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

Use JSON.stringify(), it can help you on how to avoid character escaping